# Qt build with build script

Tags: qt, build

i would like to compile my Qt Project in our build server(Windows).
i would like to create a build script that will compile my project in release.
Can someone help me write this build script?

Thanks!

Comment: I checked that, and I also see many questions with answers without feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to run qmake and then run make for Unix-like platforms. For release mode add:

```
CONFIG+=release
```

to your .pro file or to the qmake command.
Then (spec only if you know you need it):

```
path_to_your_qmake/qmake [-spec spec] [CONFIG+=release]
make [-jwhatever]
```

and you're done.

Comment: i'm trying C:\Users\tmussai\untitled>qmake.exe untitled.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG
+=declarative_debug"

C:\Users\tmussai\untitled>make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ok, then read the FAQ also.

Comment: You shouldn't put `CONFIG+=release` to your `.pro` file. You should run `qmake CONFIG+=release` instead. The project file is meant to be something that can result in everything necessary without modification.

Comment: got it, now if i'm using windows which command should i use please?

Comment: i add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools to my PATH environrment vriables but still nmake is not recognize

Comment: @rubenvb Absolutely right. Edited my answer.

Comment: ok, now i'm getting NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop. when running make command